# Splunk: how to create a diagram of multiple variables?

Tags: charts, splunk

Please look at the following table:

[image]

Suppose there are N different countries in the table.
I want to write a search line in Splunk that returns a graph that will be divided to N parts (one part per each country), while each part gives the distribution of men and women in each country.

I want that the general pattern of the graph will look like this:

[image]

For each country there will be two bars...

What search query will you write to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can search by like this :

```
index = index_name |stats count(Gender) by Country
```

Then you can go to visulaization tab choose the graphical representation whichever you want

Comment: what does "index" and "index_name" mean? Are they saved words in Splunk?

Comment: `index`  is keyword pointing to the schema where your data is stored so if you data is stored in schema named as Person:
so you wil search like `index =Person` then the rest of your query

Comment: Can you recommend a good tutorial for Splunk? The free info in Splunk site is not clear enough for me...

Comment: https://www.udemy.com/data-analytics-using-splunk/
You can access this course . Its good.

Comment: Then if you want free then Splunk education is the best source for it :
http://www.splunk.com/view/SP-CAAAH9U